# How do I include background images in my stylesheets in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, css

I'm trying to specify a background image in a style in a plugin I'm making. I was just outputing  tags from the php, but realized I should probably be using enqueue_style... But how do I put a line of code like this:

```
.star.half {
    background:url(<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/my-plugin/images/star-half.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

Into a plain .css file? What do I put where it says `<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a **STYLE** tag in `'wp_head'`.

```
// Anonymous function, PHP 5.3+, extract function for 5.2
add_action('wp_head', function(){
    echo '<style type="text/css">';
    // Add background style here
    echo '</style>';
});
```

Add this in your `functions.php`. Don't stuff too much CSS in it, just the dynamic bg image you need.

It's not the easiest thing to create a dynamic CSS file so, just for a bg image, use this method.